# How should I add a text on a image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background-image

I just want to add some calculation result on the image. So I need to set the text with the background image. But I tried several times, the image still can't display.
The code is

```
  <div style="background-image=url(<%= root_url%>public/images/1.jpg)"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have a typo in your CSS, the `=` right after `image` should be replaced by `:`:

```
<div style="background-image: url(<%= root_url %>public/images/1.jpg)"></div>
```

Second, there's no need to do this. This should work:

```
<div style="background-image: url(<%= image_url '1.jpg' %>)"></div>
```

As others have mentioned, you will propably have to set the `width` and `height` of your `<div>` in your stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

Add these to your styles attribute also

```
width:150px;height:150px;display:block;background-repeat:none
```

Obviously the width and height being those of your image, or greater than

Comment: I've tried the width and height before. The page has a blank field for the div. But the image can't display also. I'm not sure whether the image address brings the issue. But the image_tag("/images/1.jpg") can work well.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a try with

```
<div style="background-image:url('/images/1.jpg'); height: 300px; width: 500px;"></div>
```